# Where is piecewise_construct for boost::container::map::emplace()?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

**Using Boost**, I am trying to `emplace()` a key/value pair into a `boost::container::map`.  The value needs multiple arguments for the constructor.  From what I've been able to find, I need to use `piecewise_construct` and pass the constructor args in `tuples`.  This works with `std::map<K,V>`, but I can't get it to work using `boost::container::map<K,V>`  The [closest Boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/unordered/compliance.html) I can find shows `boost::unordered_multimap<K,V>`, but not a plain `map<K,V>`.

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

class A {
  public:
    /**/    A( int ) { }
    bool    operator<( const A & ) const { return false; }
} ;

class B {
  public:
    /**/    B( int, const char * ) { }
} ;

int
main( int, char ** )
{
    A    a( 100 );
    B    b( 200, "foo" );

    std::map<A,B> mgood;

    mgood.emplace( std::piecewise_construct,
                   std::make_tuple( 100 ),
                   std::make_tuple( 200, "Hello" ) );

#if 1
    boost::container::map<A,B>    mbad;

    mbad.emplace( boost::unordered::piecewise_construct,
                  boost::make_tuple( 300 ),
                  boost::make_tuple( 400, "World" ) );
#endif
}
```

The g++-4.9.2 error messages are impenetrable (to me, anyway):

> make -k tst g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK   -g -std=c++11   -c -o tst.o
>   tst.cc In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
>                    from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp: In
>   instantiation of âstatic void
>   boost::container::allocator_traits::priv_construct(boost::move_detail::false_type,
>   Allocator&, T*, Args&& ...) [with T =
>   boost::container::container_detail::pair; Args = {const
>   boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&, boost::tuples::tuple, boost::tuples::tuple}; Allocator =
>   boost::container::new_allocator, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true> >;
>   boost::move_detail::false_type =
>   boost::move_detail::integral_constant]â:
>   /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:353:86:
>   required from âstatic void
>   boost::container::allocator_traits::construct(Allocator&,
>   T*, Args&& ...) [with T = boost::container::container_detail::pair; Args = {const boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&,
>   boost::tuples::tuple,
>   boost::tuples::tuple}; Allocator =
>   boost::container::new_allocator, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true> >]â
>   /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/node_alloc_holder.hpp:167:81:
>   required from
>   âboost::container::container_detail::node_alloc_holder::NodePtr
>   boost::container::container_detail::node_alloc_holder::create_node(Args&& ...) [with Args = {const
>   boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&, boost::tuples::tuple, boost::tuples::tuple}; Allocator =
>   boost::container::new_allocator >; ICont =
>   boost::intrusive::rbtree_impl, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>,
>   boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits,
>   (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>,
>   void,
>   boost::container::value_to_node_compare, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>,
>   boost::intrusive::tree_value_compare,
>   std::less,
>   boost::container::container_detail::select1st >
>
> > > , long unsigned int, true, void>; boost::container::container_detail::node_alloc_holder::NodePtr =
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::tree_node,
> > >       void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>*]â
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:922:94:   required
> > >       from
> > >       âstd::pair,
> > >       Options:: tree_type, Options:: optimize_size>::type::iterator, false>,
> > >       bool> boost::container::container_detail::tree::emplace_unique(Args&& ...) [with Args =
> > >       {const boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&,
> > >       boost::tuples::tuple,
> > >       boost::tuples::tuple}; Key = A; T = std::pair;
> > >       KeyOfValue =
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::select1st >;
> > >       Compare = std::less; Allocator =
> > >       boost::container::new_allocator >; Options =
> > >       boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u,
> > >       true>; typename
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::intrusive_tree_type,
> > >       Options:: tree_type, Options:: optimize_size>::type::iterator =
> > >       boost::intrusive::tree_iterator, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>,
> > >       boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits,
> > >       (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>,
> > >       false>]â /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:665:72:
> > >
> > >       required from âstd::pair, boost::container::container_detail::select1st >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator, bool> boost::container::map::emplace(Args&& ...) [with Args = {const
> > >       boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&, boost::tuples::tuple, boost::tuples::tuple}; Key = A; T = B;
> > >       Compare = std::less; Allocator =
> > >       boost::container::new_allocator >; MapOptions =
> > >       boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u,
> > >       true>; typename boost::container::container_detail::tree,
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::select1st >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator, void*, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>,
> > >       boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits,
> > >       (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>,
> > >       false>, false>]â tst.cc:90:53:   required from here
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: error:
> > >       no matching function for call to
> > >       âboost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const
> > >       boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_t&, boost::tuples::tuple, boost::tuples::tuple)â
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note:
> > >       candidates are: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:146:4: note:
> > >       template
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(std::pair<_U1,
> > >       _U2>&&)
> > >           pair(BOOST_RV_REF_BEG std::pair BOOST_RV_REF_END p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:146:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note: 
> > >       types âstd::pair<_T1, _T2>â and âconst
> > >       boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_tâ have incompatible
> > >       cv-qualifiers
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:141:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(std::pair<_T1,
> > >       _T2>&&) [with T1 = A; T2 = B]
> > >           pair(BOOST_RV_REF_BEG std::pair BOOST_RV_REF_END p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:141:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:137:4: note:
> > >       template
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const
> > >       std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)
> > >           pair(const std::pair& p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:137:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note: 
> > >       âconst boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_tâ is not derived
> > >       from âconst std::pair<_T1, _T2>â
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:132:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const
> > >       std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with T1 = A; T2 = B]
> > >           pair(const std::pair& x)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:132:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:126:4: note:
> > >       template
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(U&&, V&&)
> > >           pair(BOOST_FWD_REF(U) u, BOOST_FWD_REF(V) v)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:126:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note: 
> > >       candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:120:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const T1&,
> > >       const T2&) [with T1 = A; T2 = B]
> > >           pair(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:120:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:115:4: note:
> > >       template
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(boost::container::container_detail::pair&&)
> > >           pair(BOOST_RV_REF_BEG pair BOOST_RV_REF_END p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:115:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note: 
> > >       types âboost::container::container_detail::pairâ and
> > >       âconst boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_tâ have incompatible
> > >       cv-qualifiers
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:110:4: note:
> > >       template
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair&)
> > >           pair(const pair &p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:110:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:25:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:10: note: 
> > >       âconst boost::unordered::piecewise_construct_tâ is not derived
> > >       from âconst boost::container::container_detail::pairâ
> > >              {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward(args)...); }
> > >                 ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp:36:0,
> > >                        from /usr/local/include/boost/container/map.hpp:30,
> > >                        from tst.cc:59: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:105:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(boost::container::container_detail::pair&&) [with T1
> > >       = A; T2 = B]
> > >           pair(BOOST_RV_REF(pair) p)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:105:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:100:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair(const
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair&) [with T1 = A; T2 =
> > >       B]
> > >           pair(const pair& x)
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:100:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
> > >       /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:95:4: note:
> > >       boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair() [with T1 = A;
> > >       T2 = B]
> > >           pair()
> > >           ^ /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:95:4: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided : recipe for target
> > >       'tst.o' failed make: *** [tst.o] Error 1 make: Target 'tst' not remade
> > >       because of errors.
>
> Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Apr  2 17:11:28

Can you point me in a useful direction?  (I'd prefer not to mix `boost` and `std` containers; it *should* be possible to `emplace` into a `boost::container::map`, right?)

Comment: Use code blocks (indent by 4) for compiler output, not quotes.  They are more code-like than English-like.

Comment: piecewise construct fed to emplace works because the std pair supports it.  The object being constructed in the boost case is `boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair`.  I would personally debug this by either go to definition on that in ide, or creating a simpler failure by trying to piecewise construct that `boost::container::container_detail::pair::pair` directly and examining still long, but shorter, error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

piecewise_construct support for both C++03 and C++11 capable compilers was added in commit:

https://github.com/boostorg/container/commit/79a75f470e75f35f5f2a91e10fcc67d03b0a2160

and will be officially released in Boost 1.62. The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>

class A {
  public:
    /**/    A( int ) { }
    bool    operator<( const A & ) const { return false; }
} ;

class B {
  public:
    /**/    B( int, const char * ) { }
} ;

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    A    a( 100 );
    B    b( 200, "foo" );

    boost::container::map<A,B>    m;

   //1) Both Boost.Tuple and std tuple supported
   //2) std:: or boost::container::piecewise_construct supported
    m.emplace( boost::container::piecewise_construct,
               boost::make_tuple( 300 ),
               boost::make_tuple( 400, "World" ) );

    m.emplace( std::piecewise_construct,
               std::make_tuple( 400 ),
               std::make_tuple( 500, "World2" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `piecewise_construct` is not implemented for `boost::pair` (which is the type for `boost::container::map` entries).  *See* `.../boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:151`:

```
   //piecewise_construct missing
   //template <class U, class V> pair(pair<U, V>&& p);
   //template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
   //   pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<Args1...> first_args,
   //        tuple<Args2...> second_args);
```

I guess the implementation for this is tough.